# set missing values for multiple labelled variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, r-haven

How to I set missing values for multiple labelled vectors in a data frame. I am working with a survey dataset from spss. I am dealing with about 20 different variables, with the same missing values. So would like to find a way to use lapply() to make this work, but I can't.

I actually can do this with base R via as.numeric() and then recode() but I'm intrigued by the possibilities of haven and the labelled class so I'd like to find a way to do this all in Hadley's tidyverse

Roughly the variables of interest look like this. I am sorry if this is a basic question, but I find the help documentaiton associated with the haven and labelled packages just very unhelpful.

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)
v1<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v2<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v3<-data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
lapply(v3, val_labels)
lapply(v3, function(x) set_na_values(x, c(5,6)))
```

Comment: I am having a tough time understanding exactly what you are trying to do.  Your example data does not appear to have any missing values or labels.  Am I missing something?

Comment: dear @spindoctor can you take the dataset and provide and example with `dput(<structure>,"")` and add that to your code example. Either complete or subset would be helpful. nb. I updated the code you posted `data_frame()` should be `data.frame()`

Comment: I want to convert the values 5 and 6 in each variable so that R reads them as missing when converting from a labelled class to a numeric or factor class.

Comment: @spindoctor No problem - you didn't call out a dependency on dplyr. What I was asking for was a subset of the actual data. You can create that by using base::dput() - which writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file. For future reference - it is useful to show the data input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: Maybe you should just use use.missings = TRUE parameter in foreigh::read.spss function when reading SPSS data? This would do it automatically for every column depending on the missing values definitions in SPSS data.

Comment: Is `v3[] = lapply(v3, set_na_values, c(5, 6))` not what you want?

Comment: @spindoctor many of these answers have become extremely long and complex when there's a very simplistic way of making the code in your question work the way you expected (see my answer). Can you please update your question if that's not what you're looking for anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `set_na_values` is a data frame, not a vector/column, which is why your `lapply` command doesn't work. You could build a list of the arguments for `set_na_values` for an arbitrary number of columns in your data frame and then call it with `do.call` as below...

```
v1<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v2<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v3<-data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
na_values(v3)

args <- c(list(.data = v3), setNames(lapply(names(v3), function(x) c(5,6)), names(v3)))
v3 <- do.call(set_na_values, args)
na_values(v3)
```

**Update:** You can also use the assignment form of the `na_values` function within an `lapply` statement, since it accepts a vector as it's first argument instead of a data frame like `set_na_values`...

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)
v1<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v2<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v3<-data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
lapply(v3, val_labels)
na_values(v3)

v3[] <- lapply(v3, function(x) `na_values<-`(x, c(5,6)))
na_values(v3)
```

or even use the normal version of `na_values` in the `lapply` command, just making sure to return the 'fixed' vector...

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)
v1<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v2<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v3<-data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
lapply(v3, val_labels)
na_values(v3)

v3[] <- lapply(v3, function(x) { na_values(x) <- c(5,6); x } )
na_values(v3)
```

and that idea can be used inside of a `dplyr` chain as well, either applying to all variables, or applying to whatever columns are selected using `dplyr`'s selection tools...

```
library(haven)
library(labelled)
library(dplyr)
v1<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v2<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
v3<-data.frame(v1=v1, v2=v2)
lapply(v3, val_labels)
na_values(v3)

v4 <- v3 %>% mutate_all(funs(`na_values<-`(., c(5,6))))
na_values(v4)

v5 <- v3 %>% mutate_each(funs(`na_values<-`(., c(5,6))), x)
na_values(v5)
```

Answer (score 11):

Ok, I think I understand now what you trying to do...

i.e. Mark the labels, and the values as NA without removing the underlying imported data...

***See addendum for a more detailed example that uses a public data file to show an example that harnesses `dplyr` to update multiple columns, labels...***

## Proposed Solution

```
df <- data_frame(s1 = c(1,2,2,2,5,6), s2 = c(1,2,2,2,5,6)) %>%
  set_value_labels(s1 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6), 
                   s2 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk = tagged_na("5"), refused = tagged_na("6"))) %>%
  set_na_values(s2 = c(5,6))


val_labels(df)
is.na(df$s1)
is.na(df$s2)
df
```

---

## Solution Result:

```
> library(haven)
> library(labelled)
> library(dplyr)
> df <- data_frame(s1 = c(1,2,2,2,5,6), s2 = c(1,2,2,2,5,6)) %>%
+   set_value_labels(s1 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6), 
+                    s2 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk = tagged_na("5"), refused = tagged_na("6"))) %>%
+   set_na_values(s2 = c(5,6))
> val_labels(df)
$s1
   agree disagree       dk  refused 
       1        2        5        6 

$s2
   agree disagree       dk  refused 
       1        2       NA       NA 

> is.na(df$s1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> is.na(df$s2)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
> df
# A tibble: 6 × 2
         s1        s2
  <dbl+lbl> <dbl+lbl>
1         1         1
2         2         2
3         2         2
4         2         2
5         5         5
6         6         6
```

#### Now we can manipulate the data

```
mean(df$s1, na.rm = TRUE)
mean(df$s2, na.rm = TRUE)

> mean(df$s1, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 3
> mean(df$s2, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 1.75
```

### Use Labelled package to remove labels and replace with R NA

If you wish to strip the labels and replace with R NA values you can use `remove_labels(x, user_na_to_na = TRUE)`

#### Example:

```
df <- remove_labels(df, user_na_to_na = TRUE)
df
```

#### Result:

```
> df <- remove_labels(df, user_na_to_na = TRUE) 
> df
# A tibble: 6 × 2
     s1    s2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     2
3     2     2
4     2     2
5     5    NA
6     6    NA
```

--

## Explanation / Overview of SPSS Format:

IBM SPSS (The application) can import and export data in many formats and in non-rectangular configurations; however, the data set is always translated to an SPSS rectangular data file, known as a system file (using the extension *.sav). Metadata (information about the data) such as variable formats, missing values, and variable and value labels are stored with the dataset.

#### Value Labels

Base R has one data type that effectively maintains a mapping between integers and character labels: *the factor*. This, however, is not the primary use of factors: they are instead designed to automatically generate useful contrasts for linear models. Factors differ from the labelled values provided by the other tools in important ways:

SPSS and SAS can label numeric and character values, not just integer values.

### Missing Values

All three tools (SPSS, SAS, Stata) provide a global “system missing value” which is displayed as `.`. This is roughly equivalent to R’s `NA`, although neither Stata nor SAS propagate missingness in numeric comparisons: SAS treats the missing value as the smallest possible number (i.e. -inf), and Stata treats it as the largest possible number (i.e. inf).

Each tool also provides a mechanism for recording multiple types of missingness:

- Stata has “extended” missing values, .A through .Z.
- SAS has “special” missing values, .A through .Z plus ._.
- SPSS has per-column “user” missing values. Each column can declare up to three distinct values or a range of values (plus one distinct value) that should be treated as missing.

#### User Defined Missing Values

SPSS’s user-defined values work differently to SAS and Stata. Each column can have either up to three distinct values that are considered as missing or a range. `Haven` provides `labelled_spss()` as a subclass of `labelled()` to model these additional user-defined missings.

```
x1 <- labelled_spss(c(1:10, 99), c(Missing = 99), na_value = 99)
x2 <- labelled_spss(c(1:10, 99), c(Missing = 99), na_range = c(90, Inf))

x1
#> <Labelled SPSS double>
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 99
#> Missing values: 99
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value   label
#>     99 Missing
x2
#> <Labelled SPSS double>
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 99
#> Missing range:  [90, Inf]
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value   label
#>     99 Missing
```

#### Tagged missing values

To support Stata’s extended and SAS’s special missing value, haven implements a tagged NA. It does this by taking advantage of the internal structure of a floating point NA. That allows these values to behave identical to NA in regular R operations, while still preserving the value of the tag.

The R interface for creating with tagged `NA`s is a little clunky because generally they’ll be created by haven for you. But you can create your own with tagged_na():

#### Important:

Note these tagged NAs behave identically to regular NAs, even when printing. To see their tags, use print_tagged_na():

#### Thus:

```
    library(haven)
    library(labelled)
    v1<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6))
    v2<-labelled(c(1,2,2,2,5,6), c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=tagged_na("5"), refused= tagged_na("6")))
    v3<-data.frame(v1 = v1, v2 = v2)
    v3
    lapply(v3, val_labels)
```

---

```
> v3
  x x.1
1 1   1
2 2   2
3 2   2
4 2   2
5 5   5
6 6   6
> lapply(v3, val_labels)
$x
   agree disagree       dk  refused 
       1        2        5        6 

$x.1
   agree disagree       dk  refused 
       1        2       NA       NA
```

#### Word of caution:

SPSS’s user-defined values work differently to SAS and Stata. Each column can have either up to three distinct values that are considered as missing, or a range. Haven provides `labelled_spss()` as a subclass of labelled() to model these additional user-defined missings.

I hope the above helps

Take care
T.

## References:

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/haven.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/haven/vignettes/semantics.html
- https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-missing-values-tutorial/

## Addendum Example using Public Data...

#### SPSS Missing Values Example using an SPPS Data file {[hospital.sav](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/downloads/hospital.sav)}

Firstly, let's make sure we highlight that

- **System missing values** - are values that are completely absent from the data
- **User missing values** are values that are present in the data but must be excluded from calculations.

## SPSS View of Data...

Let's review the image and the data... The SPSS data shown in the variable view shows that each row has a **Label** [Column5], we note that rows 10 through 14 have specific values attributed to them [1..6] [Column 6] that have name attributes and that no values have been specified as **Missing** [Column 7].

[image]

Now let's look at the SPSS data view:

Here we can note that there is missing data... (See hilighted "."'s). The key point is that we have **Missing data**, but currently have no **"Missing User Values"**

[image]

### Now let's turn to R, and load the data into R

```
hospital_url <- "https://www.spss-tutorials.com/downloads/hospital.sav"
hospital <- read_sav(hospital_url, 
                     user_na = FALSE)
head(hospital,5)

# We're interested in columns 10 through 14...
head(hospital[10:14],5)
```

#### Result

```
> hospital_url <- "https://www.spss-tutorials.com/downloads/hospital.sav"
> hospital <- read_sav(hospital_url, 
+                      user_na = FALSE)
> head(hospital,5)
# A tibble: 5 × 14
  visit_id patient_id first_name surname_prefix last_name    gender entry_date entry_time
     <dbl>      <dbl>      <chr>          <chr>     <chr> <dbl+lbl>     <date>     <time>
1    32943      23176    JEFFREY                 DIJKSTRA         1 2013-01-08   16:56:10
2    32944      20754       MARK        VAN DER      BERG         1 2013-02-01   14:24:45
3    32945      25419     WILLEM                VERMEULEN         1 2013-02-02   10:01:43
4    32946      21139      LINDA                  JANSSEN         0 2013-02-10   10:24:39
5    32947      25419     WILLEM                VERMEULEN         1 2013-02-10   18:05:59
# ... with 6 more variables: exit_moment <dttm>, doctor_rating <dbl+lbl>, nurse_rating <dbl+lbl>,
#   room_rating <dbl+lbl>, food_rating <dbl+lbl>, facilities_rating <dbl+lbl>
```

### Columns 10 through 14 contain Values

```
1="Very Dissatisfied"
2="Dissatisfied"
3="Neutral"
4="Satisfied"
5="Very Satisfied"
6="Not applicable or don't want to answer"
```

thus:

```
> head(hospital[10:14],5)
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  doctor_rating nurse_rating room_rating food_rating facilities_rating
      <dbl+lbl>    <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>         <dbl+lbl>
1             5            5           4           2                 3
2             4            5           4           3                 3
3             5            6           4           5                 4
4             4            5           5           4                 4
5             5            5           6           6                 6
```

## SPSS Value Labels

```
> lapply(hospital[10], val_labels)
$doctor_rating
                     Very dissatisfied                           Dissatisfied 
                                     1                                      2 
                               Neutral                              Satisfied 
                                     3                                      4 
                        Very satisfied Not applicable or don't want to answer 
                                     5                                      6
```

ok, note that above we can confirm we have imported the Value Labels.

## Remove Non-Applicable data from the survey data

Our goal is to now remove the **"Not applicable or don't want to answer"** data entries by setting them to be **"User NA values"** i.e. An SPSS **missing value**.

Solution - Step 1 - A Single Column

We wish to set the missing value attribute across multiple columns in the data... Let first do this for one column...

***Note we use `add_value_labels` not `set_value_labels` as we wish to append a new label, not completely overwrite existing labels...***

```
d <- hospital
mean(d$doctor_rating, na.rm = TRUE)

d <- hospital %>% 
  add_value_labels( doctor_rating = c( "Not applicable or don't want to answer" 
                                       = tagged_na("6") )) %>%
  set_na_values(doctor_rating = 5)

val_labels(d$doctor_rating)
mean(d$doctor_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
```

---

```
> d <- hospital
> mean(d$doctor_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4.322368
> d <- hospital %>% 
+   add_value_labels( doctor_rating = c( "Not applicable or don't want to answer" 
+                                        = tagged_na("6") )) %>%
+   set_na_values(doctor_rating = 6)
> val_labels(d$doctor_rating)
                     Very dissatisfied                           Dissatisfied 
                                     1                                      2 
                               Neutral                              Satisfied 
                                     3                                      4 
                        Very satisfied Not applicable or don't want to answer 
                                     5                                      6 
Not applicable or don't want to answer 
                                    NA 
> mean(d$doctor_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4.097015
```

## Solution - Step 2 - Now apply to multiple columns...

```
mean(hospital$nurse_rating)
mean(hospital$nurse_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
d <- hospital %>% 
  add_value_labels( doctor_rating = c( "Not applicable or don't want to answer" 
                                       = tagged_na("6") )) %>%
  set_na_values(doctor_rating = 6) %>%
  add_value_labels( nurse_rating = c( "Not applicable or don't want to answer" 
                                     = tagged_na("6") )) %>%
  set_na_values(nurse_rating = 6)
mean(d$nurse_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
```

## Result

Note that nurse_rating contains "NaN" values **and** NA tagged values.
The first mean() call fails, the second succeeds but includes "Not Applicable..." after the filter the "Not Applicable..." are removed...

```
> mean(hospital$nurse_rating)
[1] NaN
> mean(hospital$nurse_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4.471429
> d <- hospital %>% 
+   add_value_labels( doctor_rating = c( "Not applicable or don't want to answer" 
+                                        = tagged_na("6") )) %>%
+   set_na_values(doctor_rating = 6) %>%
+   add_value_labels( nurse_rating = c( "Not applicable or don't want to answer" 
+                                      = tagged_na("6") )) %>%
+   set_na_values(nurse_rating = 6)
> mean(d$nurse_rating, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 4.341085
```

## Convert tagged NA to R NA

Here we take the above tagged NA and convert to R NA values.

```
d <- d %>% remove_labels(user_na_to_na = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is very thorough, but the core of what I am trying to solve is right here:

`df <- data_frame(s1 = c(1,2,2,2,5,6), s2 = c(1,2,2,2,5,6)) %>%
set_value_labels(s1 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6), 
s2 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk = tagged_na("5"), refused = 
tagged_na("6"))) %>%
#Am I going to have to set these values for each variable, line by line; 
#I'd like a way to do this for multiple variables at once. Something like 
#lapply(x, function(x) set_na_values(x=c(5,6)) or 
#set_na_values(s1:s2=c(5,6))
set_na_values(s2 = c(5,6))`

Comment: @spindoctor - Maybe I am missing something here. I am assuming you are importing the SPSS data file with the labels via Haven. **Correct?** If so you can use the imported label data to set `tagged_na()`, and then use `remove_labels(x, user_na_to_na = TRUE)`. Can you provide a data sample? FYI: The PURR::map() function is a better typesafe equivalent of lapply - both could then be used to iterate over the dataset.

Comment: @spindoctor - Are you adding the labels after importing a file, or manipulating the labels that already exist in the file after reading into memory.

Comment: I'm doing the latter!

Comment: @spindoctor - Take a look at updated solution with public data set working across multiple columns... Take care T.

Comment: Thanks so much Technophobe; I really appreciate the time!

Comment: @spindoctor - No worries - always happy and willing to help. Take care and have a great day. T.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
v1 <- labelled(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6), c(agree = 1, disagree = 2, dk = 5, refused = 6))
v2 <- labelled(c(1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6), c(agree = 1, disagree = 2, dk = 5, refused = 6))
v3 <- data_frame(v1 = v1, v2 = v2)

lapply(names(v3), FUN = function(x) {
  na_values(v3[[x]]) <<- 5:6
})

lapply(v3, na_values)
```

The last line returning

```
$v1
[1] 5 6

$v2
[1] 5 6
```

**Verify missing values**:

```
is.na(v3$v1)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: I can get that far, that doesn't actually set the missing values though

Comment: How does it not define 5 and 6 to be `NA` values? What do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Is this correct?

```
#Using replace to substitute 5 and 6 in v3 with NA
data.frame(lapply(v3, function(a) replace(x = a, list = a %in% c(5,6), values = NA)))
#   x x.1
#1  1   1
#2  2   2
#3  2   2
#4  2   2
#5 NA  NA
#6 NA  NA
```

I know labelled_spss allows you to specify `na_range` or even a vector of `na_values`

```
#DATA
v11 = labelled_spss(x = c(1,2,2,2,5,6),
                    labels = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6),
                    na_range = 5:6)

#Check if v11 has NA values
is.na(v11)
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

v22 = labelled_spss(x = c(1,2,2,2,5,6),
                    labels = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6),
                    na_range = 5:6)

#Put v11 and v22 in a list
v33 = list(v11, v22)

#Use replace like above
data.frame(lapply(X = v33, FUN = function(a) replace(x = a, list = is.na(a), values = NA)))
#   x x.1
#1  1   1
#2  2   2
#3  2   2
#4  2   2
#5 NA  NA
#6 NA  NA
```

Comment: this is close, but I was hoping there would be a way to do something like this with the commands provided in the labelled package.

Comment: @spindoctor - Can you clarify do you just want to use the SPSS label to convert the value to an R NA value. i.e. Search for label replace value with R NA and wipe underlying data. Correct?

Comment: See updated answer - you can use `remove_labels(df, user_na_to_na = TRUE)` this strips labels that are marked as NA and replaces them with an R defined NA value.

Answer (score 2):

## Defining SPSS-style user-defined missing values

### Main functions

The two main functions in `labelled` package for manipulating SPSS style user-defined missing values are `na_values` and `na_range`.

```
library(labelled)
v1 <-c(1,2,2,2,5,6)
val_labels(v1) <- c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6)
na_values(v1) <- 5:6
v1

<Labelled SPSS double>
[1] 1 2 2 2 5 6
Missing values: 5, 6

Labels:
 value    label
     1    agree
     2 disagree
     5       dk
     6  refused
```

### set_* functions

The `set_*` functions in `labelled` are intended to be used with `magrittr` / `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
d <- tibble(v1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6), v2 = c(1:3, 1:3))
d <- d %>%
  set_value_labels(v1 = c(agree=1, disagree=2, dk=5, refused=6)) %>%
  set_na_values(v1 = 5:6)
d$v1

<Labelled SPSS double>
[1] 1 2 2 2 5 6
Missing values: 5, 6

Labels:
 value    label
     1    agree
     2 disagree
     5       dk
     6  refused
```

## What are user-defined missing values?

User-defined missing values are just and only meta-information. It doesn't change the values in a vector. This is simply a way to say to the user that these values could/should be considered in some context as missing values. It means that if you compute something (e.g. mean) from your vector, these values will still be taken into account.

```
mean(v1)
[1] 3
```

You can easily convert user-defined missing values to proper `NA` with `user_na_to_na`.

```
mean(user_na_to_na(v1), na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 1.75
```

There are very few functions that would take into account these meta-information. See for example the `freq` function from `questionr` package.

```
library(questionr)
freq(v1)
             n    % val%
[1] agree    1 16.7   25
[2] disagree 3 50.0   75
[5] dk       1 16.7   NA
[6] refused  1 16.7   NA
NA           0  0.0   NA
```

## What is the difference with tagged NAs ?

The purpose of tagged NAs, introduced by `haven`, is to reproduce the way Stata is managing missing values. All tagged NAs are internally considered as `NA` by **R**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a very simple solution in using `base` R:

```
v3[v3 == 5 ] <- NA
v3[v3 == 6 ] <- NA
```

But if you're looking for a really fast solution, you can use a `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(v3)

for(j in seq_along(v3)) { 
            set(v3, i=which(v3[[j]] %in% c(5,6)), j=j, value=NA) 
            }
```